# Does FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method set MembershipUser.LastLoginDate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I do programmatic login of my users and I use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method to create authentication cookie and add it to the response cookies collection. One thing confuses me regarding the LastLoginDate. LastLoginDate documentation says that it only gets updated when ValidateUser is called. Does  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method also set the LastLoginDate or should I set it manually?

Comment: No it doesn't.  It would be unusual to set it manually if you're using Membership, because normally in this case you will be calling ValidateUser, either explicitly or implicitly because you are using a Login control.  Without code it's impossible to say what's best in your case.

Comment: @Joe The thing is my portal is a link in another site where the users already logged in. In order to avoid multiple logins, when a link is clicked the other portal makes a request to my authentication page and I authenticate and send it to them so that next request they make to their landing page is allowed. I cannot use ValidateUser because it requires password.

Comment: in that case, you're arguably abusing the LastLoginDate semantics, as it would normally only be updated whenever a username/password is validated.  But if that's what you want, you can do so: set MembershipUser.LastLoginDate to DateTime.UtcNow, then call UpdateUser.

Comment: @Joe It's strange that SetAuthCookie is not updating the last login date since it authenticates the user.

Comment: not so strange.  It does what it says on the tin, sets an auth cookie.  Don't forget, FormsAuthentication has no knowledge of Membership and can work with other authentication methods than Membership.

Comment: @Joe How can it be that you authenticate the person independent of the mechanism used to authenticate which is membership in this instance? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The flow is typically: 1. Call Validate User with user name and password, this updates last login if successful. 2. Call a mechanism to generate an auth token. 3. Call SetAuthCookie if cookie auth is enabled - not every site/app uses cookie based authentication, some use headers, others use query string tokens, etc.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid SetAuthCookie method accepts username as input. If it was totally independent of membership, then why to accept username that membership uses?

Comment: @neo - but it provides no guarantee that the user name is valid either. See the section entitled "Forms authentication control flow" on [Explained: Forms authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/Library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_iisauthentication) - step 6 states "The server validates user credentials against a store, such as a SQL Server database or an Active Directory user store. Code in the logon page creates a cookie that contains a forms authentication ticket that is set for the session." and the code sample shows calls to validate and set cookies.